# How do you set up multiple multithreaded QWebViews in PyQt?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, qwebview

I am trying to make an application in Python using PyQt that can fetch the generated content of a list of URLs and process the fetched source with the help of multiple threads. I need to run about ten QWebViews at once. As ridiculous as that might sound, when it comes to hundreds of URLs, using threaded QWebViews gets the results over 3 times faster than normal.

---

Here is the test code that I have been having problems with...

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self, url, frame):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.frame = frame
    def run(self):
        self.frame.load(QUrl(self.url))
        print len(self.frame.page().mainFrame().toHtml())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
webFrame = QWebView()

workerList = []
for x in range(1):
    worker = Worker('http://www.google.com', webFrame)
    workerList.append(worker)
for worker in workerList:
    worker.start()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Above, I tried initializing the *QWebView* in the main ***QApplication*** only to get:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
```

So then I tried initializing the *QWebView* in the ***QThread***; but then, the *QWebView* remained unchanged and blank without outputting any errors or anything. This was probably due to a cache error.

---

I have the feeling that I am missing out on something or skipping a very important step. Since *threaded QWebViews in PyQt* isn't a really documented topic, I would really appreciate any help on how to successfully implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your question and code:

- You are talking about *QWebFrame*, but are actually passing a *QWebView* to your worker(s).  Since this is a *QWidget*, it belongs to the main (GUI) thread and should not be modified by other threads.
- One *QWebView* / *QWebFrame* can only load one URL at a time, so you cannot share it across multiple workers.
- *QWebFrame.load()* loads data asynchronously, i.e. a call to *load()* returns immediately and there will be no data to read yet.  You will have to wait for the *loadFinished()* signal to be emitted before you can access the data.
- Since the actual loading is done by the networking layer of the operating system, and the *load()* method does not block, there is no need to run it in a separate thread in the first place.  Why do you claim that this should be faster -- it makes no sense.
- Since you want to load hundreds of URLs in parallel (or about 10, you are mentioning both in the same sentence), are you sure that you want to use *QWebFrame*, which is a *presentation* class?  Do you actually want to render the HTML or are you just interested in the data retrieved?

Comment: I'm sorry, when I said **QWebFrame** I _meant_ **QWebView**. I re-edited the post with the changes.

Comment: Also, QWebView renders the page _and_ executes the javascript. The fact of it being able to execute and render javascript is absolutely crucial as it is the only reason I'm using PyQt in the first place. If I just needed the HTML data, I would have just used urllib2 and would have been finished with this a long time ago.

Comment: Well, it appears that I was looking for a wrong solution. Just like you said, **QWebView.load()** is an asynchronous function. Therefore, that defeats the whole purpose of having to use threads. Thank you.

Comment: so the only feasible solution is to launch multiple instances of the python script?